# Resultado ordenado de A a Z

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classificação

Tenho um consulta, que imagino seja em php orientado a objetos, que no meu caso estou em inicio de estudos(sei que estou atrasado).

Estou com uma plataforma Xtech, e na hora de exibição de algumas caracteristicas, tenho o seguinte codigo

```
{% if product.properties|count > 0 %}
                        <div class="clearfix">
                            {% for prop in product.properties %}
                                {% if properties_flatten[prop.id].image is not empty %}
                                    <img src="{{ host_url("uploads/images/small/" ~ properties_flatten[prop.id].image) }}">
                                {% else %}
                                    <h5>{{ properties_flatten[prop.id].excerpt }} {{ properties_flatten[prop.id].name }}</h5>
                                {% endif %}

                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
{% endif %}
```

Este código exibe as características do produto, Cor: Branco, Preto, Azul, Vermelho.

Gostaria de colocar em ordem alfabética o resultado.

Azul, Branco, Preto.

Mas não sei como fazer isso neste tipo de orientação a objetos.

Por favor se alguém souber e puder ajudar.

Me desculpem se estiver falando besteira.

Obrigado

Comment: Olá. Não tenho reputação suficiente para comentar. Porque não fazer a ordenação diretamente na query no seu banco de dados? Assim você não teria o trabalho de selecionar a informação, depois ordená-la no seu código. Deixe o banco de dados gerenciar isto pra você.

Comment: Eu não conheço esta sintaxe, então realmente não faço ideia da tech utilizada ai, mas em muitos frameworks, o objeto vem com metodos para ajudar nisso, um exemplo seria no foreach que você roda o prop, chamar algo no estilo `prop.orderBy('desc')`. Se você souber dizer que tecnologia é essa, vai ajudar. De repente um link para documentaçao.

Comment: Alias, `product.properties.groupBy('desc')`

Comment: @DavidDias - obrigado, irei analisar. agradeço a pronta resposta.